# CSS Font name in lower case?

Tags: css, webfonts, cloudflare

Does it matter if it is "Arial" or "arial" ?

With cloudflare's css minify enabled -

```
font: 16px 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

turn to

```
font:16px roboto,sans-serif;
```

Will this be an issue ?

Comment: have you tried doing it and checking by yourself?

Comment: Seems to be working, but it will be difficult for me to check every platform, so asking the experts :)

Comment: The [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-family-casing) says: "User agents must match these names case insensitively". Note the "must". This means that if a browser, or any parser, does not match a font name insensitively, it's a bug.

Comment: Do you have rocket loader enabled in cloudflare backpanel? Have you installed any other cache service?

Comment: This might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602586/on-which-operating-systems-or-browsers-are-css-font-family-names-case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

**It should not matter if you capitalize font names or not in style sheets in 2021**, unless you are using XHTML, an XML parser, or on a case-sensitive platform like UNIX. Most browsers going all the way back to the 1990's had parsers designed to ignore font-family case and didn't require capitalized font names to locate the right fonts. CSS2/CSS3 require browsers to be case-insensitive with font names.

Many purists still say its required to use properly cased font names, but its not. It likely will not hurt you, if you do. I try and capitalize font-names for the open source crowd that might be viewing one of my websites or need to revert to using XHTML5.

**SUPPORT OLDER BROWSERS**

If you want to support some much older browsers, **make sure you use double-quotes around font names with spaces**, like `"Times New Roman"`, as some older browsers (pre-2001) would fail on single quotes (IE3) or no quotes (Netscape 4). Also do try and **use lowercase for font family names like `sans-serif`**, again to support a few minor bugs in very old browsers which had issues with upper case family names (early Mozilla / Gecko browsers).